# Scala-Gatling How to use Array.length to iterate/loop a post request and passing sequential array indexed value in post request?

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, gatling, scala-gatling

Scala-Gatling How to use Array.length to iterate/loop a post request and passing sequential array indexed value  in post request?
Gatling :
From the response of the below request I saved a String vector value/ String array value

```
.exec(http("testing")
.post("/testUrl")
.formParam("testvalue", "Testalert")
.check(jsonPath("$[*].id").findAll.saveAs("TestID"))) 
// datatype : vector string / single dimensional array
```

I have to iterate the below request with testID.length and pass the array indexed value (TestID[i] in to the json page

```
repeat(testID.length) {
  exec(http("ViewTestPage")
  .post(TestUrl + "/graphql")
  .body(ElFileBody("testpage/testPageView.json"))
 // pass value TestID[i], i++ at each iteration
  .check(status.is(200)))
}
```

for example :
testPageView.json file contains

```
{"query":"query{api{test(limit:${TestID[i]}){edges{node{id type{role}}}}\"}
```

Please suggest a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop instead of `repeat` to expose the current element on each iteration, see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#foreach

Comment: I couldn't understand the syntax seq().
can you provide an example for my case please